# How can I add the Gaussian fit function back to originlab?

Tags: gaussian, originlab

I needed to do a project for school to fit multiple peaks using the Gaussian function. The problem is that I remove the function accidentally from the peak functions list.This is preaty much all am I seeing. I don't know how to add it back and I didn't find anything else on google. Maybe because this is not something people usually do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoU38.png)
When I press the "add" button I don't see anything in the folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQndV.png)
But when I look directly in the folder I see the function right there. Maybe it is a Gaussian function for something else, not peak fit. Does anybody know how I can fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxxvC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using ordinary least squares ols curve fitting to interpolate a line between the two peaks

```
  # Fit the data to the gaussian function.
    fit_func = lambda p, x: p[0]*np.exp(-0.5*((x-p[1])/p[2])**2) + p[3]
    err_func = lambda p, x, y: fit_func(p, x) - y
    p0 = [max_counts, max_location, sigma, baseline]
    p, success = optimize.leastsq(err_func, p0[:], args=(x, y))
    
    # Get the parameters of the Gaussian function.
    max_counts, max_location, sigma, baseline = p
```